# Hide span when search bar is filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to react.js. I have this problems.
When I start typing a country name and pick a suggestion from the search bar the span still showing that suggestion.
And even when I submit the search an the result list is displayed the span still showing.

```
    const search = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await props.onCitySearch(data)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    const onKeyDown = (e: any) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            props.onCitySearch(data);
            setQuery('');
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((p) => {
            setPosition(p.coords);
        });
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (query === "") {
            setData([]);
            return;
        }

        const path = position === null
            ? `http://localhost:8080/suggestions?q=${query}&page=0`
            : `http://localhost:8080/suggestions?q=${query}&latitude=${position.latitude}&longitude=${position.longitude}&page=0`

        try {
            fetch(path)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(({ cities }) => setData(cities));
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }

    }, [query, position])

    return <div className="SearchBar">
        <input
            ref={inputRef}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            value={query}
            onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}></input>

        <button onClick={search}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={!isLoading ? faSearch : faCircleNotch} className={isLoading ? 'fa-spin' : ''} />
        </button>

        <div className="suggestions">
            {data.map((suggestion, key) => <div key={key} onClick={() => { setQuery(suggestion.ascii) }}>
                <span>{suggestion.ascii}</span>
            </div>)}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should set the data to empty array on selecting any of the suggestion from the list.  


{data.map((suggestion, key) => <div key={key} onClick={() => { setQuery(suggestion.ascii);
setData([]);
 }}>
                <span>{suggestion.ascii}</span>
            </div>)}

Comment: It did not work it just empty the list but the div still showing when the input is filled

Comment: you should render the suggestions div only if data array is not empty.

{data.length ===0 ? null : <div className="suggestions">
            {data.map((suggestion, key) => <div key={key} onClick={() => { setQuery(suggestion.ascii) }}>
                <span>{suggestion.ascii}</span>
            </div>)}</div>}